# How to play the microphone audio using DirectSound or API?

Tags: c#, microphone, directsound, cscore

I want to real time playing the audio microphone input.

If do it using `DirectSound`. I can get the audio data from Buffer but I don't know how to play the data I get.

If do it using API: I got a `C++` example this morning.

It's use some API functions such as "waveInOpen".But I know very little about `C++`.And I don't know how to use these API  functions in other programming language...

So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSCore](http://cscore.codeplex.com) to do that:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var capture = new WasapiCapture())
    {
        capture.Initialize();

        using(var source = new SoundInSource(capture))
        {
            using(var soundOut = new WasapiOut())
            {
                capture.Start();

                soundOut.Initialize(source);
                soundOut.Play();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good!Simple and practical...Thank a lot!